# Powermock SerializationIssue

Tags: maven, serialization, junit4, powermock, powermockito

When I add the [Powermock depenencies](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven) to my maven project I get the following error message:

[image]

The project has the following dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the following version numbers:

```xml
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <powermock.version>1.6.2</powermock.version>
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mockito-core` in Maven builds. `mockito-all` is for people using legacy build systems.

The latest version of mockito 1.x series is 1.10.19 so try that.